# emberjs - strange workaround for filtering based on controller property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to figure out why filtering on a controller's property directly is not working as expected.

controller:

```
var VideoIndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

  genreFilter: "",
  actions: {

    filterGenre: function(genre) {
        this.set("genreFilter", genre);
    }
  },

  genres: function() {
    var genres = this.get('content').map(function(video) {
        return video.get("GenreName");;
    }).filter(function(genre, index, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(genre) == index;
    });
    console.log("genres", genres);
    return genres
  }.property("content"),

  filteredContent: function() {
    var content = this.get("arrangedContent");
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(this.get("genreFilter"))) {
        return content.filterBy("GenreName", this.get("genreFilter").valueOf());
    } else {
        return content;
    }
  }.property("arrangedContent", "genreFilter")

});
```

console.log for genres:

```
["Youth/Children", "Movies", "Actuality/Information", "Series", "Shows", "Sport", nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function, getEach: function…]
0: "Youth/Children"
1: "Movies"
2: "Actuality/Information"
3: "Series"
4: "Shows"
5: "Sport"
__ember1384338760148_meta: Meta
_super: undefined
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
```

template:

```
{{outlet}}

<a href="" {{action "filterGenre"}}>All</a>
{{#each genres}}
<a href="" {{action "filterGenre" this}}>{{this}}</a>
{{/each}}

<a href="" {{action "sortAZ"}}>A-Z</a>
<a href="" {{action "sortZA"}}>Z-A</a>
<a href="" {{action "sortSuggested"}}>Suggested</a>

<section >
{{#each filteredContent}}
    {{#linkTo 'catchup/item' this}}
    <div class="catchup-list-item">
        {{#if thumbnailUrl}}
            <div>
                <img {{bindAttr src="thumbnailUrl"}} />
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <div {{bindAttr class=":title validDownloadUrl::invalid"}}>
            <div>{{ProgramName}}</div>
            <div>{{subTitle}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}
</section>
```

notice the 2nd parameter in `content.filter()`

if I call this like:

`content.filterBy("GenreName", this.get("genreFilter"));`

then the returned array is always empty.

adding `.valueOf()` gives me the expected output. This seems pretty cumbersome and error prone.

edit: note that I am using `arrangedContent`, as I have some snipped actions that perform sorting

edit2: updated to include template

edit3: added genres array console log

Comment: Can you show the action that call the `filterGenre` action?

Comment: added the template to my question

Comment: also please add the `genres` array

Comment: added console log output for genres array

Answer (score 1):

The `filteredContent` should be a computed property of `arrangedContent.[]`, not `arrangedContent`. The `arrangedContent` is an array, and you need to tell Ember to list for array changes (items added, items removed).

Having said that I would guess that the `{{action "filterGenre" genre}}` is not passing the right property. I guess it should be a string, but it passes an Object. That's why when you call `valueOf()` it produces the expected result. The `filterBy` function expects a string and  in that case the JS interpreter passes it through `toString()` first.

It would be helpful if you can post the actual template where the action is called, or give some log output for the value of `genreFilter`.

Comment: added the template to my question